# ValueError: could not convert string to float: '"815745789754417152"'

Tags: python

This is error code

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [42], in <cell line: 3>()
      1 from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier as knn
      2 classifier=knn(n_neighbors=5)
----> 3 classifier.fit(X,y)
      4 bots = training_data[training_data.bot==1]
      5 Nbots = training_data[training_data.bot==0]
```

After result show this error

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '"815745789754417152"'
```

My code using

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFpuA.png)

Comment: Strip the quotation marks off.

Comment: I alr update my question is new version

Answer (score 1):

The string itself seems to be `"815745789754417152"`. It can't convert " to a numeric value.
You can strip it off by:

```
string = string[1:-1]
```

Comment: mean like? because my code now is


from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier as knn
classifier=knn(n_neighbors=5)
classifier.fit(X,y)
bots = training_data[training_data.bot==1]
Nbots = training_data[training_data.bot==0]
 
B = bots.iloc[:,:-1]
B_y = bots.iloc[:,9]
B_pred = classifier.predict(B)

#Confusionmatrix
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
cm=confusion_matrix(B_y,B_pred)
Performance(B_y,B_pred)

NB = Nbots.iloc[:,:-1]
NB_y = Nbots.iloc[:,9]
NB_pred = classifier.predict(NB)

Comment: First of all, code in comments (involving more than one line) is unreadable. Second, I do not know what your dataset looks like. But if your dataset has entries in with quotation marks around it, you should first preprocess that column to strip those off, before you run your model.

Comment: Well, I've changed and added to my original code at this question，you can check